# How to make Dirty Read?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, transactions, dirtyread

Will this be an example of Dirty Read?

T1 & T2 transactions

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

[Dirty read example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rLI3.png)

Comment: What environment is this, even? Transact-SQL?

Comment: yes T SQL environment

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to construct a "dirty read" by looking at the `MyCleanTable`

```
Id | Value
----------
1  | I am clean!
2  | I am clean!
```

---

1. Execute a simple query transaction_a with uncommitted isolation level

   ```
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

   BEGIN TRAN

       SELECT * FROM [MyCleanTable]
   ```

The OUTPUT:

```
Id | Value
----------
1  | I am clean!
2  | I am clean!
```

2. Update the table with a dirty value with transaction_b:

   ```
    BEGIN TRAN

        UPDATE [ConcurrencyDemo].[dbo].[MyCleanTable]
        SET [Value] = 'I am dirty'  
        WHERE [Id] = 1
   ```
3. Execute another query within transaction_a and commit it:

   ```
       SELECT * FROM [ConcurrencyDemo].[dbo].[MyCleanTable]

   COMMIT;
   ```

The OUTPUT:

```
Id | Value
----------
1  | I am dirty! ------> "dirty read"
2  | I am clean!
```

4. Rollback the update of transaction_b:

   ```
   ROLLBACK;
   ```

At this stage the table was rolled back into its original values:

```
Id | Value
----------
1  | I am clean!
2  | I am clean!
```

But the query of section 3 was reading a dirty value.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a dirty read.  The details of what that does are here: [implicit transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql)

To get a dirty read, you need to put select column1 from dbo.table1 WITH (NOLOCK).  The With (NOLOCK) reads uncommitted data which might disappear and never really exist if the transaction is rolled back in some way.

The other way to get a dirty read is to use: isolation level read uncommitted.

Answer (score 1):

[image: dirty read]
[image]

1. Transaction One starts
2. Transaction Two starts
3. Transaction One do an update operation
4. Transaction Two do a select operation and see the dirty data generated by Transaction One
5. Transaction One commit or rollback

In order to realize dirty read, we should execute the following command first

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Dirty read** is that a transction reads the uncommitted data which other transactions insert, update or delete.

I experimented **dirty read** with **MSSQL(SQL Server)** and **2 command prompts**.

First, I set **`READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level** to occur **dirty read**:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Then, I created **`person` table** with **`id`** and **`name`** as shown below.

#### `person` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **David** |

Now, I did **these steps below** with **MSSQL queries**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** **`GO;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** **`GO;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 2;`** **`GO;`** **2 David** |  | **T1 reads `David`.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Tom' WHERE id = 2;`** **`GO;`** | **T2 updates `David` to `Tom`.** |
| **Step 5** | **`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 2;`** **`GO;`** **2 Tom** |  | **T1 reads `Tom` instead of `David` before T2 commits.** #### ***Dirty read occurs!!** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`COMMIT;`** **`GO;`** | **T2 commits.** |
| **Step 7** | **`COMMIT;`** **`GO;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |